# Save/merge rows in DataTable to database without depending on row state accuracy?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datatable

I need to write a method in C# to save all rows in a given datatable back to the database, but I cannot depend on the rowstate of each row.  I can't think of how best to do this without extensive looping through the database table data or constant database querying.

I want to essentially perform the following insert / update for each row in the datatable, but more efficiently:

```
INSERT INTO table
(   col1,
    col2    )
SELECT
    'value1',
    'value2'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = 'value1' );

UPDATE table
SET col2 = 'value2'
WHERE col1 = 'value1';
```

I was thinking a structure like this would be the most efficient:

```
private void SaveDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
{
    //Remove data from the dataTable where it already exists in the database

    //Determine if the values are to be inserted or updated

    //Save relevant data
}
```

Any ideas on how best to accomplish this?

Comment: As long as there is a single transaction, and their are indices, multiple *upserts* are just fine (but there are better ways to write them: follow the keyword). The "most efficient" would likely be a MERGE, but that's non-standard and would not necessarily be noticeably better in said scenario.

Comment: [Here is an approach using SqlBulkCopy + temp + MERGE](http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/) for a "Bulk Upsert". Neat, but likely overkill for smaller workloads.

Comment: Yes, col1 is a PK in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am unable to avoid querying for each row in the given datatable, I think this will work for now.  Thanks for your responses; they were all very helpful.

(Oracle specific):

```
internal override bool RecordExists(DataRow row)
{
    string query = string.Concat("SELECT 1 FROM ", row.Table.TableName, " ", GetDbTableFilter(row, row.Table.PrimaryKey), " AND ROWNUM = 1");

    using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, (OracleConnection)_connectionLibrary.CurrentConnection))
        using(OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            return (reader != null && reader.Read());
}

internal override string GetDbTableFilter(DataRow row, DataColumn[] columns)
{
    string filter = "";

    foreach (DataColumn column in columns)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
            filter += " AND ";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[column].ToString()))
        {
            filter += string.Concat("(", column.ColumnName, " IS NULL OR TRIM(", column.ColumnName, ") = '')");
            continue;
        }

        if (column.DataType.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
        {
            filter += string.Concat(column.ColumnName, " = TO_DATE('", row[column].ToString(), "')");
            continue;
        }

        filter += string.Concat(column.ColumnName, " = '", row[column].ToString(), "'");
    }

    return string.Concat("WHERE ", filter);
}

public override void SaveDataTable(DataTable dataTable)
{
    dataTable.AcceptChanges();

    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        if(RecordExists(row))
            row.SetModified();
        else
            row.SetAdded();

    using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", dataTable.TableName), (OracleConnection)_connectionLibrary.CurrentConnection))
        using (OracleCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OracleCommandBuilder(adapter))
        {
            commandBuilder.SetAllValues = true;
            commandBuilder.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;

            adapter.InsertCommand = commandBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
            adapter.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);

            adapter.Update(dataTable);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of approaching it from an application point of view, I strongly recommend you let the database manage this.  SQL Server is optimized for set operations, and you basically want to perform two set operations:

- Update all records that exist in the table that differ from the records that also exist in your [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)
- Insert all the records in your `DataTable` that don't exist in the table

To that end, I recommend creating a new table, `tableStaging`:

```
create table tableStaging (
    batchId uniqueidentifier not null, col1 int not null, col2 int not null)
```

A few important points:

- The `batchId` column allows you to identify multiple operations being performed at the same time by different callers of your application.  You want to generate this value *once* for each set that you're performing this operation on, not each record.
- The `batchId` column is a [`uniqueidentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) because it translates to a [`Guid` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) and that can easily be generated on the client side with a call to [`Guid.NewGuid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx).
- You might want to have a compound primary key that consists of the `batchId` and whatever the primary key is of the `table` table to make the upcoming operations more efficient.

Once you do that, you use the [`SqlBulkCopy` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to bulk insert the records from your `DataTable` ([there's an overload of `WriteToServer` that takes a `DataTable` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx)).

Finally, once the records are in the `tableStaging` class, you can call a stored procedure that simply executes an [`update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) for all items where the `batchId` column and the primary key exist between the two tables, an [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335) for items that exist in the staging table and not in the target table.  Or, if you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use the [`merge` statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) and do both in one shot.

Then, it's just a matter of cleaning up the staging table.  Since you have the `batchId` when you call the stored procedure/run the commands, you can delete the records when you're done updating your main table, or, you can wait until a time where you know no one will use this and call [`truncate table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx) on the table (the staging table should *not* have foreign keys, so `truncate table` should work just fine).